# Using Groovy (ActiveXobject) to Import a Dll in SOAP UI

Tags: soap, user-interface

I am using groovy script to use a class from a dll in soap ui using ActiveXobject and i am getting the following error each time i invoke it..

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script15.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class
>   ActiveXObject @ line 3, column 15. def signLib = new
>   ActiveXObject('iop.systemtest.tools.signlib.SignLibForSoapUI') ^
>   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class
>   ActiveXObject @ line 3, column 15. at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:148)
>   at

Below is the piece of the scripts i am using

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.*
def signLib = new ActiveXObject('iop.systemtest.tools.signlib.SignLibForSoapUI');
```

Any one has any idea. ???